# Create a JTree from a list of dot-delimited Strings

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode, treemodel

I am creating an editor application, and I am having a problem with my menus. In the object menu, I want to display several objects types using a `JTree`. These object types are dynamically registered by plugins and follow this style:

```
trigger.button
trigger.lever
out.door.fallgate
trigger.plate
out.door.door
...
```

This list of names is unsorted and I want to build a `TreeNode` structure for a `JTree` like this:

- trigger

  - button
  - lever
  - plate
- out

  - door

    - fallgate
    - door

Additionally, if the user selects a leaf node, I need to recreate the object name (e.g. trigger.button) from the `TreePath`. Could someone please advise how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In psuedocode, this is what you need to do...

```
public TreeNode buildTree(){
    String[] names = new String[]; // fill this with the names of your plugins

    TreeNode tree;

    // for each plugin name...
    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        String currentName = names[i];
        String[] splitName = currentName.split(".");

        // loop over the split name and see if the nodes exist in the tree. If not, create them
        TreeNode parent = tree;
        for (int n=0;n<splitName.length;n++){
            if (parent.hasChild(splitName[n])){
                // the parent node exists, so it doesn't need to be created. Store the node as 'parent' to use in the next loop run
                parent = parent.getChild(splitName[n]);
            }
            else {
                // the node doesn't exist, so create it. Then set it as 'parent' for use by the next loop run
                TreeNode child = new TreeNode(splitName[n]);
                parent.addChild(child);
                parent = child;
            }
        }

return tree;
}
```

This is only psuedocode - you'll need to do the work of implementing the TreeNode methods properly, etc. Give it a try yourself - if you have any more problems, create a question and show us that you've attempted to do it yourself, then we will be more willing to help you solve the minor problems.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to 'tick' this answer if you think its the best, so that everyone else knows your problem was solved.

Comment: Here is an additional method to get the name of object from the treePath:

    public static String getElementName(TreePath path) {
        Object[] nodes = path.getPath();
        String result = "";
        //read the path, start from index 1 because we don't want the root
        for (int i=1; i<nodes.length; i++) {
            result += nodes[i];
            //add separator
            if (i!=nodes.length-1)
                result += ".";
        }
        return result;
    }

Answer (score 1):

- see [Oracle JTree tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)
- part [Dynamically Changing a Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic), check the code example
- [similair idea](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingaNodetoaJTreeComponent.htm)